# Simple JQuery .css() command not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

It's been some time since I've used JQuery, so this might be something very obvious.

I am attempting to use JQuery to set the colour of all text inside `<span>` tags which has a class containing a certain keyword (in this example, the word inside the class tag is "var").

I then put this jQuery code into the body of the document:

```
$("class*='var'").css("color", "#FF00DC");
```

But this doesn't make any difference.

Is there a simple syntax error I'm making here or is this something a bit deeper? I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vw4Qj/25/) to try and illustrate the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector syntax is wrong, it should be `$("[class*='var']")` (see [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)).

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$("[class*='var']").css("color", "#FF00DC");
```